# Compare the annual rates between groups

Tags: r, math, rate, fpgrowth

I am strugling into comparing the rates 'of mortality' between two percentages over time interval. My goal is to get the annual rates per group.

My values are already in percentages (`start` and `end` values), representing how mych forest have been lost (disturbed, burned, cut, etc.) over several years from the total forest cover. E.g in first year it was 1%, the last year 20 % is a cumulative value of total forest lost.

I followed the calculation of the [Compound annual growth rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_annual_growth_rate) (**CARG**), taking into account the values in the 1st year, last year, and total number of years.

Here are my dummy data for two groups, eg. mortablity depending between tree species:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c('pine', 'beech'),
                 start = c(1,2),
                 end = c(19, 30),
                 years = 18)
```

To calculate the CAGR, I have used this function:

```
CAGR_formula <- function(end, start, yrs) {
  values <- ((end/start)^(1/yrs)-1)
  return(values)
}
```

giving:

```
df %>% 
 mutate(CARG = CAGR_formula(end, start, yrs)*100)

  group start end yrs     CARG
1  pine     1  19  18   17.8
2 beech     2  30  18   16.2
```

However, CARG rates of 16-17% seems awefully hight! I was expecting about 1-3% per year. Please, what is wrong in my formula? Is it because original values (start, end) are already in percentages? Or, is it because `end` is a cumulative values of the `start`?

Thank you for your ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, maybe this is what is desired:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(CARG = CAGR_formula(1 - end/100, 1, yrs)*100)

#>   group start end yrs      CARG
#> 1  pine     1  19  18 -1.163847
#> 2 beech     2  30  18 -1.962024
```

where the `start` parameter to `CARG()` is always 1 (the value for year 1 can be ignored in this calculation), meaning the forest is 100%, and the `end` parameter to `CARG()` is `1 - end/100`, e.g. in the first row 81% of the forest remains after 18 years.

The resulting yearly mortality rates are 1.17% and 1.96%.

We can verify that 1 * (1 - 0.0117)^18 is roughly 81%, and 1 * (1 - 0.0196)^18 is roughly 70%

Comment: Thank you @Aurèle, this adaptation with the starting number 1 (100% of forest) instead starting with the damage have likely made a trick, and lead to more expected calculation rates. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Why does it seem high? From 1% to 19% is a big jump. Also:
`1 * 1.178^18 = 19.086`

Seems right to me