# Calculate annual rates from the gam model over time?

Tags: r, gam, rate

Question moved to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588138/calculate-annual-rates-from-the-gam-model-over-time)

---

I am trying to express the difference in the 'speed of increase' between two categories in `gam` modelling. My data represents the cumulative values over time [0-100%], but I wish (for comparability with other studies) to express them in yearly values. I wonder if it is even meaningfull, if my models are `gam`, and therefore non-linear?

Previously, to calculated the 'annual values' per two groups by the Compound annual growth rate (CARG) from the starting and ending values/number of years from the `gam` predicted values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808291/compare-the-annual-rates-between-groups). Now, I wonder if **is it somehow possible get those value from the model itselft**, and converted to annual increase? Something, like 'Betas' from 'glm' to show that one predictor is more important then the other?

My data looks like this: I have two groups, with the cumulative rate of forest loss over time (ranging between 0-100% from no forest loss to complete forest loss). Eg. group `yellow` has predicted lost ~ 40 % of forest from 2000 to 2017, group `blue` has predicted lost ~ 10 % over the same time. My dummy data are available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dup-Gv8xLX6TqIiHGNFAYVQuG8ASx-Y3/view?usp=sharing) and in `dput` form below. My pseudo-code model: `forest_loss ~ year + location`, where different groups represent different location.

```
# Restructure the data first
  dd$location = as.factor(dd$location)  # claim grouping variable as factor
  dd$forest_loss <- dd$forest_loss/100  # the the values between 0-1

# Plot the gam model
   ggplot(dd, aes(x = year, 
                y = forest_loss, 
                group = location,
               color = location)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'gam', 
              method.args = list(family = "betar"),
              formula = y~s(x, bs = 'cs'))  + 
  geom_point()
```

My dummy model is in a formula similar to this: `m1<-bam(y ~ s(x, by = grp) + grp, dd, family = betar)` (I am using the form as used for the real data, althought I have more predictors there), based on `bam/gam`. Family `betar` is because by predicted values ranges between 0-100 (0-1).

This is the dummy example so some part of teh code (`gam`) can produce errors. But my main question is **how to express the annual increase per group from the cumulative values themselves?** Is it already accessbible from `summary(m1)`, and it is meaningfull?

Thank you for your thoughts.

[image]

Dummy data [(shared as suggested here using the `dput`)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stack-overflow)

```
   dd<- structure(list(year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L), forest_loss = c(2, 2.5, 2.7, 2.9, 2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 
3.1, 4, 5, 5.6, 5.8, 5.9, 6.7, 7.2, 9, 10, 3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.5, 
3.5, 7, 7.2, 8, 15, 19, 22, 25, 27, 29, 32, 33, 35, 40), location = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("blue", "yellow"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

Answer to comments:

somehow, the `tidymv::plot_smooths(m1)` provides an error:

```
Error in `parse_expr()`:
! `x` must contain exactly 1 expression, not 0.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Output from the `summary(m1)`

```
Family: Beta regression(75.174) 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
y ~ s(x, by = grp)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -2.671      0.083  -32.19   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                 edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
s(x):grpblue   1.000  1.000  11.64 0.000647 ***
s(x):grpyellow 3.684  4.547 283.12  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.952   Deviance explained =   85%
-REML = -64.262  Scale est. = 1         n = 36
```

Partial effect by gratia: `gratia::draw(m1, scales = 'free')`

[image]

Comment: This question might be better suited in [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Some observations: 1) The plot you show is a loess curve (what geom_smooth uses by default), not a generalized additive model. 2) You use family = betar in your bam model when your data is not bounded between 0 and 1. 3) Your model on the example data does not fit the data properly (try plotting m1 with tidymv::plot_smooths, trained on your dummy data). 4) I think what you are after is simply summary(m1).

Comment: @Ventrilocus re 2) I suspect they are plotting on a % scale (given how they describe the problem in terms of %) - I doubt the model would even fit if provided data like this as Simon's `betar` family would set all the response data to some value just a little less than 1

Comment: Thank you all ofr your thoughts. I have tried to update my question by answering to each comment. Still, somehow I even can properly fit the model itself: `m1~gam(y ~ s(x, by = grp), data = dd, method = 'REML', family = betar)` as I am geting error ` inner loop 3; can't correct step size`, which I do not understand? My preudocode should looks like this: `forest_loss~year + location`. Thank you again ofr your thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `plot_smooth` from `tidymv` you should specify the `series` and `comparison` argument like this:

```r
library(mgcv)
library(tidymv)
dd$location = as.factor(dd$location)  # claim grouping variable as factor
dd$forest_loss <- dd$forest_loss/100  # the the values between 0-1

m1<-bam(forest_loss ~ s(year, by = location) + location, dd, family = betar)
tidymv::plot_smooths(m1, year, location)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>